# Determining multiple space separated inputs in C buffer

Tags: c, strstr

I have been trying to justify my logic while reading in input for my command interpreter. The problem I am running into is `strstr()` either is not accepting `"%s"` as a *needle* or is treating the entire *haystack* as a string and disregarding spaces, newlines, etc because of this.

```
char command[4] = "";
char arg1[512] = "";
char arg2[512] = "";
char tmp[1029] = "";
char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
memset(buffer, '\0', BUFFERSIZE);

while(fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin) != NULL){
    strcpy(command, "");
    strcpy(arg1, "");
    strcpy(arg2, "");
    strcpy(tmp, "");
    if(strstr(buffer, "%s\n") != NULL)
        sscanf(buffer, "%s", command);  // 0 arguments
    if(strstr(buffer, "%s %s") != NULL)
        sscanf(buffer, "%s", arg1);     // 1 argument
    if(strstr(buffer, "%s %s %s") != NULL)
        sscanf(buffer, "%s", arg2);     // 2 arguments
    printf("%s %s %s\n", command, arg1, arg2);
}
```

No matter what I input:

- com
- val argument1val
- cmd arg1 arg2val
- etc

I always end up with empty character arrays for `command`, `arg1`, and `arg2`.

My input will always be a single string or up to three space separated strings followed by a newline character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to scan once and check for number of parsed arguments that `sccanf` returns (with special check for empty line entered)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 2000

int main()
{
int nb_args;
char command[4] = "";
char arg1[512] = "";
char arg2[512] = "";
char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
memset(buffer, '\0', BUFFERSIZE);

while(fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin) != NULL){
    strcpy(command, "");
    strcpy(arg1, "");
    strcpy(arg2, "");

    nb_args = sscanf(buffer, "%3s%511s%511s", command,arg1,arg2);
    if (strlen(command)==0)
    {
        printf("empty line\n");
    }
    else
    {
    switch(nb_args)
    {
        case 1:
           printf("Command = %s\n",command);
           break;
        case 2:
           printf("Command = %s, arg1 = %s\n",command,arg1);
           break;
        case 3:
           printf("Command = %s, arg1 = %s, arg2 = %s\n",command,arg1,arg2);
           break;
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This was exactly the logic I was trying to think up! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The `strstr` function does not use `printf` style format string.  It looks for the exact contents of the second argument within the first argument.

What you want to use instead is `strtok`, which will split up a string based on a delimiter which in this case is a space.

```
char *p;
p = strtok(buffer, " ");
if (p) {
    strcpy(command, p);
    p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    if (p) {
        strcpy(arg1, p);
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
        if (p) {
            strcpy(arg2, p);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will very quickly need a proper answer.
Which is to take a string containing arbitrary whitespace, trim it by removing leading and trailing whitespace, then replace all runs of whitespace characters by single spaces. Then build a list of words knowing that a single space is the delimiter.

There are other approaches, but if you write this function it will give you an understanding of how strings are laid out in memory, and how to manipulate them.